# Primefaces JSF java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter text is null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using JSF 2.0 with Primefaces 3.4.2,when I run my application, I am getting the following exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter text is null
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.writeText(HtmlResponseWriter.java:877)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeFilter(DataTableRenderer.java:450)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeColumnHeader(DataTableRenderer.java:360)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeThead(DataTableRenderer.java:551)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:218)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:192)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:74)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
```

JSF Code Snippet

```
 <p:column id="empName" headerText="Name"  filterBy="#{emp.empName}"  
                            filterOptions="#{myMB.empFilter}"  
                            filterMatchMode="exact">
                            <h:outputText value="#{emp.empName}"/> 
                        </p:column>
```

And in my ManagedBean

```
public Map<String,String> loadNames() {    
        names = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        names.put("Smith", "S");
        names.put("Jones", "J");        
        return names;    
    }

private SelectItem[] empFilter;

public void init() {
empFilter= new SelectItem[loadNames().size() + 1];
        empFilter[0] = new SelectItem("", "Select");
        for (int i=1; i< empFilter.length; i++) {
            empFilter[i] = new SelectItem(loadNames().get(i-1), loadNames().get(i-1));
    }
```

}

Comment: What is your table receiving as value from the bean?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie You mean JSF datatable or database table? I have static values which is from LinkedHashMap.

Comment: In this `#{emp.empName}` emp should be the p:dataTable var, but I don't see any object in your bean having a empName getter/setter.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie emp is indeed p:dataTable var `<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="emp" lazy="true"`

Comment: And your `value=""` is refering to `loadNames()` ?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie value for datatable is not `loadNames()` in fact it is `value="#{myMB.lazyModel}"`

Comment: Pretty sure you have one empName that is returning null.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie When I check the length of `empFilter` I can see as 4 which I have added. So didn't understand why empName return null.

Comment: Removed my bad answer and posted the good one this time!

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie I have noticed that when I changed from `Map<String,String>` and use `List<String> empList;` then there are no errors and I could see the values as drop down in JSF page.

Comment: yes exactly what I am explaining in the second answer!

Comment: Why exactly are you creating the very same map 5 times during the `init()`? This is plain inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not getting values properly from your `loadNames()` into your bottom loop.

Example :

```
Map<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
map.put("Smith", "S");
map.put("Jones", "J");

System.out.println(map.get(0));
```

will return `null`.

You need to change your loop like that :

```
public void init()
{
    empFilter= new SelectItem[loadNames().size() + 1];
    empFilter[0] = new SelectItem("", "Select");
    int i = 1;

    for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : loadNames().entrySet())
    {
        empFilter[i++] = new SelectItem(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Alexandre Lavoie it worked. Thanks a lot for pointing it correctly. Appreciated.